# Get description of an AD user with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the members of an AD group with this PS command:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "GROUP_NAME" -Recursive
```

However I want to know the "Description" field for each AD user.

Is there a way to get this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try piping `Get-ADGroupMember` to `Get-ADUser` and specifying the Description property:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GROUP_NAME" -Recursive | 
  Get-ADUser -Properties Description
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks!