# Get description field for AD users in PS

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I found [this MS script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Office-365-Role-Groups-b1eb6c6a) to extract admin users from AD. It gets the roles with `$AzureADRoles = @(Get-AzureADDirectoryRole -ErrorAction Stop)`, iterates over them, and gets the users using `$RoleMembers = @(Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $AzureADRole.ObjectId)`.

It works great, only I need to access the description field on these users. Unfortunately, the `$RoleMembers` don't have a description attribute, even though the `$AzureADRoles` do!

Is there some way I can get the description field for the users, perhaps with a similar command? I see some commands that would do the trick if I wanted to traverse group members, but I'm looking for something role-based.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `$AzureADRoles.Description`, it's that easy

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1 for your helpful reply, but I want the description on the users, not their roles.

Comment: Oh I see.  You could also use a filter in your case: `Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($RoleMember.DisplayName)'"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948704/get-description-of-an-ad-user-with-powershell). I just had to add `$Admin = Get-ADUser -Identity $RoleMember.DisplayName -Properties Description` before constructing `$ObjectProperties` in a try/catch block, then get the description from `$Admin` and grab everything else just like before.